# What's wrong in my confguration spring sessionFactory configuration?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

First of all, I can't use Spring's `@Transactional` annotation. I have to use exactly JTA which in out EJB-container. Currecntly I'm using `JBoss AS 7.0 Web-Profile`. So what I need to do is configure Hibernate's session factory to correctly work with `JTA`-transaction inside the `Spring`'s Envirnoment. My current configuration:

piece of the `context.xml` configuration:

```
<tx:annotation-driven/>
<tx:jta-transaction-manager  />

<!-- Some other beans -->

<bean id="userTransaction" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/UserTransaction"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.badmitrii.db.entity.Employee</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
        </props>            
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
    <property name="userTransaction" ref="userTransaction"></property>
</bean>
```

DAO-method:

```
public Player getPlayerById(Integer id){
    try {
        userTransaction.begin();
    } catch (Exception e) { }

    //Here is obtaining a Criteria object and setting Restrictions

    try {
        userTransaction.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) { }
    return (Player) criteria.uniqueResult();
}
```

But, I got the following excpetion when I was trying to get Session in the DAO method:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:134)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1024)
    com.badmitrii.db.dao.EmployeeDAOImpl.getEmployeeById(EmployeeDAOImpl.java:34)
    com.badmitrii.EmployeeListController.getEmployeeById(EmployeeListController.java:42)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:706)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
```

How to configure it correctly?

Comment: There is no reason why you wouldn't be able to use `@Transactional`  in a JTA environment. The whole point of `@Transactional` or declarative transactionmanagement is that it doesn't matter if it is for local or distributed transactions.

Comment: @M.Deinum If I start to use spring's transaction I'm going to have to remove all JTA-transactions in the rest of the project.

Comment: No you don't, you seem to lack understanding on this matter.

Comment: @M.Deinum Do you think it'd be a good idea to apply Spring's Transactional in the part of project where I want to use hibernate's features and JTA transactions in the rest of one?

Comment: @M.Deinum Is it ever possible to correctly configure jta+spring+hibernate?

Comment: It is all JTA but you don't need to write the tedious tx code yourself, so I would say yes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all remove the declaration for `JtaTransactionManager` as that is already provided by `<tx:jta-transaction-manager />`.

Next there is no reason why you wouldn't be able to use `@Transactional`  in a JTA environment that is the whole point of declarative tx management.

You should wire the configured jta transactionmanager to the `LocalSessionFactoryBean` to switch out the used `CurrentSessionContext`.

```
<tx:annotation-driven/>
<tx:jta-transaction-manager  />

<!-- Some other beans -->

<bean id="userTransaction" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/UserTransaction"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jtaTransactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.badmitrii.db.entity.Employee</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
        </props>            
    </property>
</bean>
```

Then in your cod eyou can simply do something like this

```
@Transactional
public Player getPlayerById(Integer id){
    //Here is obtaining a Criteria object and setting Restrictions
    return (Player) criteria.uniqueResult();
}
```

**Update:**

For JBoss the `<tx:jta-transaction-manager />` doesn't work due to fact that the `TransactionManager` for JTA is registered in JNDI under the name `java:jboss/TransactionManager` instead of one of the [well-known names](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-tx/src/main/java/org/springframework/transaction/jta/JtaTransactionManager.java#L137). You will need to declare the `JtaTransactionManager` bean yourself and remove the `<tx:jta-transaction-manager />` element. For the lookup you need to specify the `transactionManagerName` or do a JNDI lookup yourself.

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
    <property name="transactionManagerName" value="java:jboss/TransactionManager" />
</bean>
```

The `UserTransaction` is registered under the default name so you can omit the injection of it in the `JtaTransactionManager` as it will do the lookup itself.

Comment: Great, you save my time, thank you. Not it works. But I'm going to provide some notes about the configuration.

Comment: I just tried what you write and intially it didn't work. When we're declaring `org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager` we're going to have to explicitly provide the transactionManager property of the bean, otherwise an exception's going to be thrown. In my case it was JbossTransactionManager which could be found by its jndi-name `java:jboss/TransactionManager`.

Comment: Moreover, as said http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html , the `<tx:jta-transaction-manager />` annotation is going to be work for the only WebLogic Server and WebSphere.

Comment: No it isn't... For those servers a custom `JtaTransactionManager` is needed but JTA will work regardless of the server for everything else it is going to use the default `JtaTransactionManager`. However in the case of JBoss it doesn't work because they don't use one of the default names the JTA usertx and tx manager can be found.

Comment: What's the default JTA-name, couldn't you clarify a bit? Did you mean the `JNDI`-name of the TransactionManager itself?

Comment: Yes, there are some [well-known names](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-tx/src/main/java/org/springframework/transaction/jta/JtaTransactionManager.java#L137) but JBoss uses not one of those. For JEE7 there is even a default name in the spec.